# How to echo string and user input to a file

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to echo a variable into an autoexec.cfg file but I'm having some trouble with echoing a string and a variable to a file simultaneously.

I've tried putting quotes around the echo statement like

```
echo "sv_maxplayers %answer%">%location%
```

and, while it echos the string correctly, it includes the quotations marks.
(`"sv_maxplayers 4"`)

My script is currently

```
@ECHO OFF
    set location=".\Risk of Rain 2_Data\Config\autoexec.cfg"
    set /p answer="Please enter a number 1-16:"
    if %answer% GTR 0 (
        if %answer% LSS 17 (
            goto set
        )
    )
    echo Invalid argument.
    goto exit

:set    
    echo sv_maxplayers %answer%>%location%
    echo Done!
    goto exit

:exit
    pause
    exit
```

Running that returns

```
Please enter a number 1-16:4
sv_maxplayers
Done!
Press any key to continue . . .
```

in the console and clears autoexec.cfg.

It should output as

```
sv_maxplayers 4
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should use either `(Echo sv_maxplayers %answer%)>"%location%"` or `>"%location%" Echo sv_maxplayers %answer%`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution! I was missing some spaces.

`echo sv_maxplayers %answer%>%location%`
needs to be
`echo sv_maxplayers %answer% > %location%`

Comment: That isn't the best solution, simply because you're `echo`ing `%answer%<space>`. I'm not sure if it could affect the reading or parsing of your `.cfg` file, but it is unnecessary. Please take a look at my comment beneath your question where I have provided the commonly recommended methods.